# minimum cardinal for a set of sets

Tags: set-theory

Let A be a set of sets. Has A an element with minimum cardinality? 
For example, if we consider A a finite set, the A has an element (which is not necessarily unique) with minimum cardinal.
With many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A$ is not empty, a general answer will depend on whether you accept the Axiom of Choice (AoC), in the form of the Well-Ordering Principle.

If you do not accept AoC, then that implies that you are open to the possibility of non-comparable cardinalities. One example is an infinite, Dedekind-finite set (Dedekind-finite means it is not bijective with any proper subset of itself), which will be incomparable to $|\Bbb N|$, if it exists.

If you do accept the AoC, then any set has the cardinality of some ordinal number, and the set of all ordinals with the same cardinality as some element of $A$ will have a least element. You may not be able to tell *which one*, though. One common example is $\Bbb R$ and any uncountable cardinal (as long as it's reasonably small, but not the smallest one). While we know $\Bbb R$ has the cardinality of *some* ordinal (as a consequence of AoC), it's impossible to tell which.

If you do not accept the AoC, but weaken your question to ask about whether there is an element of $A$ which is not strictly larger than any other element of $A$, rather than asking about whether there is an element of $A$ which is smaller than any other element of $A$, then I don't know what the answer is.

Comment: The first example is not good in my opinion, without choice it is consist that the continuum is incomparable to some other infinite cardinality, but it is also consist it is comparable. A better example is infinite dedekind finite set. Which if exists it is incomparable to aleph0

Comment: @Holo I fixed it.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: If $S$ is an infinite Dedekind-finite set, and if $\mathcal A$ is the set of all infinite subsets of $S$, then every element of $\mathcal A$ is strictly greater than some other element of $\mathcal A$: namely, if $X\in\mathcal A$ and $x\in X$, then $X\setminus\{x\}\in\mathcal A$ and $|X\setminus\{x\}|\lt|X|$.